# DSS, VRI - what is so mystructure?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, pdfbox

I've just sign document using itext. I've **LTV** too.

[image]

> I read in itext documentation - "The DSS contains references to certificates, and we can add
>   references to OCSP responses and CRLs that can be used to re-verify
>   the certificates"

yes,  I fount them in my DSS.

> I also read thet: "In the DSS, we can store VRI"

I dont understand why is VRI for? because there is the same OCSP responses and Certificates , which are in DSS.

Also wat does  /61A2411B1..... means? is it some hash or Random number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The structures you are interested in are defined in [ETSI TS 102 778-4](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.02_60/ts_10277804v010102p.pdf).

> I dont understand why is VRI for? because there is the same OCSP responses and Certificates , which are in DSS.

While the **Certs**, **OCSPs**, and **CRLs** arrays in the **DSS** dictionary reference certificates, OCSP responses, and certificate revocation lists *that may be used in the validation of any signatures in the document,* the **VRI** dictionary contains Signature VRI dictionaries which reference the validation-related information for a single signature.

As your document contained but one signature, the information looks unnecessarily duplicated.

> Also wat does /61A2411B1..... means? is it some hash or Random number?

The key of each entry in the **VRI** dictionary is the base-16-encoded (uppercase) SHA1 digest of the signature to which it applies.

**PS:** To clarify: *key* in the last sentence refers to the PDF structure: the **VRI** dictionary is a PDF dictionary in which a key (a PDF name object) is mapped to a value (another PDF object, in this case another PDF dictionary). It is not a cryptographic key from the signature...

Thus, you take the signature in question, calculate its SHA1 hash, write it in uppercase base-16-encoding, make that string as a PDF name, and then use that PDF name as PDF dictionary key.

Comment: additional questions: 1) why is certificates duplicated?  in VRI should there  be only a signer certificate? in documentation , there is written  that, in VRI there is required Certs, OCSP, CRLS.  2)  key of sha1 digest of signature - that's digest of signer certificate, does not it? :-)

Comment: Ad 1) In **VRI/61A.../** the value of **Cert** shall be "An array of (indirect references to) streams, each containing one BER-encoded X.509 certificate (see RFC 5280 [7]). This array should contain all certificates that were used in the validation of this signature;" that's more than just a signer certificate. 2) I've clarified the answer.

Comment: sometimes there are keys in VRI too. for example if thare are OCSP and CRL in VRI, there are two such hex keys. how is them calculated? one is for OCSP and one for CRL - I think so.

Comment: Please do read the reference i have you. There you will also find how the signatures of OCSP responses and CRLs are referenced.

Comment: I have a question about the base-16 encoded key. If the key added to the pdf, doesn't that change the value of the signature itself, because the content of the pdf is changed?

Comment: You save the changes as an incremental update, i.e. by adding a new revision to the document which includes the changes. Thus, the content of the originally signed byte ranges remains, the signature remains valid as is. Checking that the incremental updates of a file only contain allowed changes (like adding validation related information), is a different task for PDF signature validators, one that many ignore or implement only erroneously.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you. And what should be the input to the SHA1 digest. I'm reading the docs, but can't quite get it. Is the whole value in the Contents entry (including zreos), should the value be converted to bytes, or the hash should be computed over hex value, and last is base-16 same as hex?

Comment: The *value* is a *byte string*, i.e. a `byte[]`. Merely its *representation* / *serialization* is hex encoded. Thus, you don't hash the hex encoded serialization but the byte array, i.e. yes, the value should be converted to bytes before hashing. That all being said, you shouldn't need to dive too deeply into this as the current version of the PAdES specs (ETSI EN 319 142-1 V1.1.1) recommends "The VRI dictionary should not be used."

Answer (score 0):

Current latest ETSI specification is at https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319100_319199/31914201/01.01.01_60/en_31914201v010101p.pdf

You can leave the VRI out as its a duplicated data and actually not needed.

> The VRI dictionary is optional, since all necessary data to validate
> the signature can be available from other sources like the DSS
> dictionary itself. The VRI dictionary offers possibilities for
> optimization of the validation process, since it relates the data to
> one specific signature.

Comment: Adobe Reader required it for a longer time than the ETSI norms did but nowadays also does not require it anymore.